# How to add pagination code to data table in vue js?

Tags: vue.js, v-data-table

I'm utilizing v-data-table in a vue component, looking through the documentation it wasn't clear to me how to utilize built in pagination in the data table and how to invoke code for the pagination . I tried to look through some of the blogs but still not clear.

```
<template>
<v-data-table
  :page="page"
  :pageCount="numOfPages"
  :headers="headers"
  ...
</template>
<script>
export default {
   name: "DataTableSample", 
   data() {
     return { 
   ...
   },
   watch: {
     options: {
       handler() {
         this.getData();
       },
     },
     deep: true,
   },
   methods: {
     load(){
       //load data
    ...
   },
   mounted(){
     this.getData();
  },
 };
</script>
```

Comment: What is 'pagination code'? An event listener of page change? Or a slot?...

Comment: thanks, i'm new to vue js and also to libraries around it. would be really helpful, if you could direct me to some sample. I was thiking of a event listerner, that is waht i'm familiar with javascript

Comment: What are you trying to do?.. if you want to create your own pagination UI and logic, so take a look at https://vuetifyjs.com/en/components/data-tables/#external-pagination

Comment: not trying to do the external pagination. i just didn't see an example of how to use inbuilt pagination , or add in built pagination and then invoke a function to call the api for the next page data

Comment: https://vuetifyjs.com/en/components/data-tables/#server-side-paginate-and-sort

Comment: thanks, may be i misunderstood the documentation in the first place. if i wanted to click on the next button for pagination and call the api for next page items. i am assuming that would be external pagination , right? if yes, that that's what i'm looking for . i apologize for the mistake

Answer (score 1):

Not sure what does this statement means *it wasn't clear to me how to utilize built in pagination in the data table and how to invoke code for the pagination* ?

But `<v-data-table>` providing pagination by default. Here is the demo **:**

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  vuetify: new Vuetify(),
  data () {
    return {
      selected: [ ],
      headers: [
        {
          text: 'Dessert (100g serving)',
          align: 'left',
          sortable: false,
          value: 'name',
        },
        { text: 'Calories', value: 'calories' },
        { text: 'Fat (g)', value: 'fat' },
        { text: 'Carbs (g)', value: 'carbs' },
        { text: 'Protein (g)', value: 'protein' },
        { text: 'Iron (%)', value: 'iron' },
      ],
      desserts: [
        {
          name: 'Frozen Yogurt',
          calories: 159,
          fat: 6.0,
          carbs: 24,
          protein: 4.0,
          iron: '1%',
        },
        {
          name: 'Ice cream sandwich',
          calories: 237,
          fat: 9.0,
          carbs: 37,
          protein: 4.3,
          iron: '1%',
        },
        {
          name: 'Eclair',
          calories: 262,
          fat: 16.0,
          carbs: 23,
          protein: 6.0,
          iron: '7%',
        },
        {
          name: 'Cupcake',
          calories: 305,
          fat: 3.7,
          carbs: 67,
          protein: 4.3,
          iron: '8%',
        },
        {
          name: 'Gingerbread',
          calories: 356,
          fat: 16.0,
          carbs: 49,
          protein: 3.9,
          iron: '16%',
        },
        {
          name: 'Jelly bean',
          calories: 375,
          fat: 0.0,
          carbs: 94,
          protein: 0.0,
          iron: '0%',
        },
        {
          name: 'Lollipop',
          calories: 392,
          fat: 0.2,
          carbs: 98,
          protein: 0,
          iron: '2%',
        },
        {
          name: 'Honeycomb',
          calories: 408,
          fat: 3.2,
          carbs: 87,
          protein: 6.5,
          iron: '45%',
        },
        {
          name: 'Donut',
          calories: 452,
          fat: 25.0,
          carbs: 51,
          protein: 4.9,
          iron: '22%',
        },
        {
          name: 'KitKat',
          calories: 518,
          fat: 26.0,
          carbs: 65,
          protein: 7,
          iron: '6%',
        }
      ]
    }
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue/dist/vue.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vuetify@2.0.0-beta.8/dist/vuetify.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vuetify@2.0.0-beta.8/dist/vuetify.min.css"/>
<div id="app">
  <v-app>
    <v-data-table 
      id="mytable"
      v-model="selected"
      :headers="headers"
      :items="desserts"
      :items-per-page="5"
      class="elevation-1"
      item-key="name"
    >
    </v-data-table>
  </v-app>
</div>
```

Comment: thanks. if you don't mind can you provide me sample on how to set up my v-data-table , such that when user clicks on next page number, some function is invoke and in that function i make a call to api to get next page data